# Does it exist a c++ container with just the first and the last value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, stl, containers

I'd need a container which would be initialized with just the first and the last value of a range.

I need a container looking like below:

```
range<int> myRange(first, last, bound);
int occur=myRange.count(r%5==0 && r%10!=0);
```

`bound` would define the distance between objects during iteration inside the container. For example, if `first=0`, `last=10` and `bound=1` iteration would be performed on every integer from `first` to `last` inclusively. If `bound=2`, iteration would be performed within {0,2,4,6,8,10}. But the size would be 2; `myRange[0]=first` and `myRange[1]=last`.

For short a container allowing iteration over non-existing objects. Iteration over first, first+bound, first+2*bound, first+n*bound until the last element is reached. I don't want to use an array.

The `count()` method would return how many objects within the range `return true` for the given condition.

N.B.I'm a beginner, so ***if*** there is a solution, please elaborate a minimum :)
Thanks for taking the time ;)

Comment: By definition, it is not a *container*. It is a *range*.

Comment: I already search for range and I found nothing.

Comment: Search harder, like: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look on that website @NickyC

Answer (score -2):

See following implementation :

> > cat range.h

```
#ifndef _RANGE_H_
#define _RANGE_H_

#include <climits>
#include <cassert>
#define expr(var) (var%5 == 0 && var%10 != 0)

class Range {
    int first;
    int last;
    int bound;
    friend class RangeIterator;

    public: 
    Range(int f, int l, int b) : first(f), last(l), bound(b) {}
    ~Range() {}

    int count() const {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = first; i <= last; i += bound) {
            if (expr(i))
                cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    int getFirst() const { return first; }
    int getLast() const { return last; }
};

class RangeIterator {
    const Range* mRange;
    int mCurrVal;

    public: 
    RangeIterator(const Range* range) : mRange(range) 
    { 
        assert(range); 
        mCurrVal = mRange->first;
    }

    ~RangeIterator() {}

    int getNext() {
        int ret = INT_MIN;
        if (mCurrVal <= mRange->last) {
            ret = mCurrVal;
            mCurrVal += mRange->bound;
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

#endif
```

> > cat main.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include "range.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Range r(0, 50, 5);

    RangeIterator ri(&r);
    int curr = INT_MIN;
    while ((curr = ri.getNext()) != INT_MIN) {
        cout << curr << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "count is : " << r.count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have hard-coded the condition using a define in implementation of count function. If you want count function to be generic enough in order to evaluate any generic expression, then I guess I would need to use regular-expression in the code. 
Before I proceed to implement that I wanted to confirm if this is really what you're looking for.

Comment: Any justification for disregarding the C++ and STL convention on *iterator* and *algorithm*?

Comment: What do you mean by C++ convention? 
I wasn't aware of existing STL iterator, so I implemented it.

Comment: Basically, *type requirement*, or *concept*. Like, increment operator, dereference operator, member types, etc. As initiated by the original STL, nowadays specified by the International Standard, well-known among C++ developers, and conformed by many third-party libraries.

Comment: oh, you mean the way iterators are implemented in STL library. I agree that style is common because of STL. But, I don't think that's the standard. We use the different style (as I mentioned) in the organization I work for.

Comment: It is not a "style". It is the definition of iterator in the C++ International Standard. It is the formal requirements specified by section 24.2 of ISO/IEC 14882:2014. Don't depreciate it into something less than that.